# Windows 7 card reader drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sd-card

I've formatted an SD card from ext3 to NTFS using Acronis. 
But after that any memory card stopped to mount in system.

I have reinstalled card reader drivers but nothing. I think it's win7 problem, because memory cards and card reader are work well.

Do you need any information about the problem?

laptop: Lenovo e320 1298-rs7.

Comment: Does it work successfuly If you use a different SD card in the reader? If so then you do **not** have card **reader** driver problems.  Instead something is wrong with the SD card or the formatting on it.  Try wiping it and reformatting with diskpart. ([start] [run] 'diskpart` `list disk` `select disk X`. `wipe`).

Comment: Anyone sd card doesn't work in card reader in windows. When I type 'list disk' i see sd card in the list.

Comment: @Hennes: I think you meant `clean` instead of `wipe`.

Comment: Oops. Correct. The `clean` command is needed to wipe the MBR/GPT info.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer insted of editing the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to set up a letter for the disk, This is how:

Start → My computer(right click) → Manage → Storage. Set up letter for defective disk. Reboot. That's all.